# SQLite subquery select statement

Tags: sql, android-sqlite

I have two tables lets assume history and Favorites

- `Favorites` schema is (id int primary key, isFav int)
- `History` schema is (id int)

`Favorites` table has => songs with id and an int (0 or 1) and history table has => series of id which may be duplicates

I want a SQL statement for selecting ids from favorites which has value = 1 and order by number of occurrence(count) in history table (it may contain or not record with that id)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT
x.id
, (
  SELECT 
     COUNT(y.id) 
  FROM y 
  WHERE y.id = x.id
  ) as YCount
FROM x
WHERE value = 1
ORDER BY  YCount;
```